# project uniform distribution in hypercube on subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let  $X$ be a random vector uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]^n$, and $P$ an orthogonal projection on a given subspace.

Is there an explicit formula for the law of $PX$ ?

Edit : I have tried direct computation for when $Im P = vect(\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\\end{pmatrix}
)$, which yielded a calculation algorithm that generates around $2^{n}$ terms of the form $Q(x)(x-\sum \pm \alpha_i)^+ $ with Q polynomial and $x^+ = max(0,x)$.

This seems to suggest the density of PX would probably contain around $2^n$  discontinuity points which probably cannot be expressed "nicely" in a formula (with linear number of terms or so).

I also tried approximating the uniform distribution with a sum of gaussian distributions (Stone theorem applies here), since the law of PX with X being a gaussian vector is still gaussian.
So if we have $\mu_X(x) = \mathbb{I}_{[-1,1]^n}(x) = \sum a_k e^{ ^tx.A_k.x }$, we'd have $\mu_{PX}(x) = \sum a_k e^{ ^tx ^tP.A_k.Px }$.

There are however ambiguous convergence issues with this method. I was hoping someone would already have an answer since the question seems elementary and already treated.

Comment: Efforts should be presented in the post body instead of in the comments :)

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ using `\max`. For operators lilke $\operatorname{Im}$ that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{Im}`.